# launch button every 2 hours without click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to launch the web page every 2 hours without click the button and every time the old page web should be closed to open the new one.
this the html page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Monitoring", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Error)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Launch" />
}
```

this is my Import method:

```
string path4 = "D:/Project/TProdPlan.xlsx";

Excel.Application application4 = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook4 = application4.Workbooks.Open(path4);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet4 = workbook4.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range range4 = worksheet4.UsedRange;
List<TProdPlan> ListTProdPlan = new List<TProdPlan>();
for (int row = 2; row <= range4.Rows.Count; row++)
{
     TProdPlan S = new TProdPlan();
     S.Num= (((Excel.Range)range4.Cells[row, 1]).Text);
     S.stat = (((Excel.Range)range4.Cells[row, 2]).Text);
     ListTProdPlan.Add(S);
 }

ViewBag.ListTProdPlans = ListTProdPlan;

//close excelsheet after reading data
workbook4.Close(0);
application4.Quit();

return View("Monitoring");
}
```

this is the "Monitoring View"

```
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
        <h1>Total Seasame Tickets Status (From 16/04 To 22/04)</h1>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead >
            <th style="text-align:center">Number</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Status</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Color Code</th>

            </thead>

            <tbody style="text-align:center">

                @foreach (var Ts in ViewBag.ListTsesames)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Ts.Number</td>
                        <td>@Ts.Status</td>
                       @if (@Ts.Status == "Resolved")
                       {

                        <td><img src="~/Web/Resolved.png" /></td>
                       }
                       else if (@Ts.Status == "Opened")
                       {
                        <td><img src="~/Web/Opened.png" /></td>
                       }
                       else if (@Ts.Status == "Assigned")
                       {
                        <td><img src="~/Web/Assigned.png" /></td>
                       }
                       else if (@Ts.Status == "PendingCustomer")
                       {
                        <td><img src="~/Web/PendingCustomer.png" /></td>
                       }
                       else if (@Ts.Status == "Closed Complete")
                       {
                        <td><img src="~/Web/Closed Complete.png" /></td>
                       }


                    </tr>

                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <br />
        <h1>Total is : 115 </h1>

        <div class="carousel-caption">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit using javascript/jquery, but if you only want to redirect a user from one page to another just use

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

javascript/jquery allows you to use timers and in the fire event of the timer you can just add the redirection code I mentioned.

```
 setInterval(yourfunction, 1000*60*60*2);
```

Comment: Post your code that you tried and we will have a look at it

Comment: i need to refresh the web page every 1 hour, i extract the data from the excel sheet and i display it in "Monitoring" view.

Comment: i used this code before `HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("refresh", "120; url=" + Url.Action("Import"));` but the web page can't be refreshed

Comment: you are trying to redirect the user from server side... this will be difficult because the user will have to request something to get to the server... rather do it on client side code(with javascript) like the code snipet examples that i provided